# UNION query not returning extra column

Tags: mysql, join, union

I've got two SQL-queries that I want to merge, I'm unfortunately not a knowledgeable user of MYSQL.

For now this is my query:

```
SELECT animal.species, count(animal.species) as f
FROM disp, animaldesc, animal 
WHERE disp.disp_id = animaldesc.disp_id 
AND animaldesc.authored = 1 
AND animaldesc.animal_id = animal.id 
GROUP BY animal.species 
union
SELECT animal.species, count(animal.species) as f_specific
FROM disp, animaldesc, animal 
WHERE disp.disp_id = animaldesc.disp_id 
AND animaldesc.authored = 1 
AND animaldesc.animal_id = animal.id 
AND disp.language = "en_gb" 
GROUP BY animal.species 
ORDER BY f DESC
```

this query is returning data like this:

```
-----------------------|--------------------
species                | f
-----------------------|--------------------
M_A_1789               | 5
-----------------------|--------------------
M_A_1789               | 1
-----------------------|--------------------
M_A_1731               | 5
-----------------------|--------------------
M_A_1731               | 1
```

Allthough I get all the data I want, the structure is wrong. I believe it has to do with using UNION in stead of doing a JOIN. I'm however unsure about which type of JOIN to use (I'm guessing right outer) as f_specific can return fewer rows than f.

I couldn't find a clear explanation to combine the two queries other than using the UNION method? How does one go about using the JOIN keyword so that my query returns this:

```
-----------------------|------------|---------------
species                | f          | f_specific
-----------------------|------------|---------------
M_A_1789               | 5          |     1
-----------------------|------------|---------------
M_A_1731               | 5          |     1
-----------------------|------------|---------------
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query you need is:

```
SELECT animal.species, 
    COUNT(animal.species) AS f, 
    SUM(IF(disp.language = "en_gb", 1, 0)) AS f_specific
FROM disp, animaldesc, animal 
WHERE disp.disp_id = animaldesc.disp_id 
    AND animaldesc.authored = 1 
    AND animaldesc.animal_id = animal.id 
GROUP BY animal.species
```

It is the first query from your `UNION` that additionally adds `1` to `f_specific` for each row that has `disp.language = 'en_gb'`. It should return the resultset you expect.

Comment: Replace `IF(disp.language = "en_gb"), 1, 0` to `IF(disp.language = "en_gb", 1, 0)`.

Comment: Yes, this query worked. There was an issue with the IF-statement, I replaced it to    ` SUM(case when disp.language = "en_gb" then 1 else 0 end) AS f_specific` Thanks!

Comment: Oh, the closing parenthesis of `IF` was misplaced. I fixed it now.